# Adding labels for each OneLineAvatarListItem Python Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Im trying to add labels for each item in OneLineAvatarListItem, but item adding only for last OneLineListItem, can i do it using python only?
My code:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineAvatarListItem

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Window.clearcolor = (100, 100, 100, 1)
        window = BoxLayout()

        screen = Screen()
    
        scroll = ScrollView()
        
        list_view = MDList()
   
        scroll.add_widget(list_view)
        
        for i in range(10):
            items = OneLineAvatarListItem(text=str(i))
            label = Label(text='www', color=[.1, .1, .1, 1])
            items.add_widget(label)
            list_view.add_widget(items)
            
            
        screen.add_widget(scroll)
       
        window.add_widget(screen)
        
        
        return window



MyApp().run()
```

[Im getting that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Lez.png)

Comment: Where exactly do you want to add `Label`, and isn't it easier to use `TwoLineListItem` for this?

Comment: I want add label for each list element to right, I may use TwoLineListItem but i don't know how to move secondary_text to right

Comment: maybe  this widget wasn't created to add other widgets - and this makes problem. You may need to build own widget from scratch.

Comment: I can't ask another question, this is off topic but how can I make OneLineAvatarListItem clickable?
is it possible?

Comment: `OneLineAvatarListItem` is already clickable - it is build with `ButtonBehavior` so it chnage color when you hover or click it. Maybe your problem is how need to assing function to item?

Comment: yes, i dont know how to assing function to item

Comment: `OneLineAvatarListItem(..., on_release=function_name)` and `def function_name(widget): print(widget.text)`

Comment: in documentation there is example how to create [CustomItem](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.0/components/list/#custom-list-item) with Checkbox on right side but the same way I added MDLabel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using example from documentation - [CustomItem](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.0/components/list/#custom-list-item) - I created custom `ListItem` with label which use `ILeftBody` to display on left side of standard text.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarListItem, ILeftBody
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel

from kivy.lang import Builder


KV = '''
<MyItemList>:

    LeftLabel:
        id: left_label

BoxLayout:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: scroll
'''


class MyItemList(OneLineAvatarListItem):
    '''Custom list item.'''

class LeftLabel(ILeftBody, MDLabel):
    '''Custom left container.'''

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(30):
            item = MyItemList(text=f"Item {i}", on_release=self.on_click_item)
            #print(item.ids)
            item.ids.left_label.text = str(i)
            
            self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(item)

    def on_click_item(self, widget):
        print('text:', widget.text, 'left_label.text:',  widget.ids.left_label.text)

MainApp().run()
```

Result:

[image]

I tried to add other label with `IRightBody` but it didn't work for me with `OneLineAvatarListItem` but work with `OneLineAvatarIconListItem` (with `Icon` in name).

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem, ILeftBody, IRightBody
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivy.lang import Builder


KV = '''
<MyItemList>:

    LeftLabel:
        id: left_label

    RightLabel:
        id: right_label
    
BoxLayout:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: scroll
'''


class MyItemList(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    '''Custom list item.'''

class LeftLabel(ILeftBody, MDLabel):
    '''Custom left container.'''

class RightLabel(IRightBody, MDLabel):
    '''Custom right container.'''
        
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(30):
            item = MyItemList(text=f"Item {i}", on_release=self.on_click_item)
            #print(item.ids)
            item.ids.left_label.text = str(i)
            item.ids.right_label.text = str(100+i)
            
            self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(item)

    def on_click_item(self, widget):
        print('text:', widget.text, 'left_label.text:',  widget.ids.left_label.text, 'right_label.text:',  widget.ids.right_label.text)

MainApp().run()
```

Result:

[image]

---

For `Label` you can use `ILeftBody`/`IRightBody` without `Touch` and it will run function assigned to ListItem. But if you want to add `Button`, `CheckButton` and assign function to this widget then it may need `ILeftBodyTouch`/`IRightBodyTouch` without `Touch`

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem, ILeftBody, IRightBodyTouch
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.button import MDTextButton
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
<MyItemList>:

    LeftLabel:
        id: left_label

    RightButton:
        id: right_button
#        on_release: app.on_click_right_button(self)
        
BoxLayout:

    ScrollView:

        MDList:
            id: scroll
'''


class MyItemList(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    '''Custom list item.'''

class LeftLabel(ILeftBody, MDLabel):
    '''Custom left container.'''

class RightButton(IRightBodyTouch, MDTextButton):
    '''Custom right container.'''
        
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for i in range(30):
            item = MyItemList(text=f'Item {i}', on_release=self.on_click_item)
                        
            #print(item.ids)
            item.ids.left_label.text = str(i)
            item.ids.right_button.text = f'More {i}'
            item.ids.right_button.on_release = lambda widget=item.ids.right_button:self.on_click_right_button(widget)  # it needs `widget=...` because created in `for`-loop
            
            self.root.ids.scroll.add_widget(item)

    def on_click_item(self, widget):
        print('--- on_click_item ---')
        print('wdiget.text:', widget.text, 'left_label.text:',  widget.ids.left_label.text, 'right_button.text:',  widget.ids.right_button.text)

    def on_click_right_button(self, widget):
        print('--- on_click_right_button ---')
        print('wdiget.text:',  widget.text)
        print('widget.parent.parent:', widget.parent.parent)
        print('widget.parent.parent.text:', widget.parent.parent.text)

MainApp().run()
```

Comment: in source code I found [another example](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/uix/list/list.py#L393) which you can't see in documentation. There is also link to [image](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HeaTTheatR/KivyMD-data/master/gallery/kivymddoc/custom-list-right-container.png)